Add extension=intl.dll in godaddy
I'm trying to enable the php intl extension in GoDaddy, but I haven't been able to.  Add the extension in the.user.ini file, I have plesk Window hosting any idea how to add it.                Extensión intl.dll php plesk window Godaddy.

Contact your service provider support, they can help for sure.
